# How to get a document by its primary key in mongoengine?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I'm porting an application from App Engine's ndb to mongoengine. ndb provides the `Model.get_by_id` method, and I'd like to implement this in terms of mongoengine. So how do you get a document by its automatically generated id, or by whatever field has `primary_key` set to True?

Comment: why don't you check the implementation of get_by_id ?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath App Engine ndb's get_by_id uses Google's datastore, whereas I'm using MongoDB, so the internals won't match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html

Answer is simple:

```
Model.objects(id='your-id')
```

I presume that you know the name of the primary key field.

Comment: I prefer this over with_id as it raises the DoesNotExist exception when the id doesn't exist where as with id returns a None object.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`with_id()`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.with_id):

```
class MyDocument(Document):
    ...
    @classmethod
    def get_by_id(cls, id):
        return cls.objects.with_id(id)
```

This will return the document instance if it exists or `None` if it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`with_id`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.with_id). It's specialized for that purpose.

```py
Model.objects.with_id('your-id')
```

It returns `None` if no object is found.

But ensure you're not setting filter (as if it was [filter method](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.base.datastructures.EmbeddedDocumentList.filter)) because it raises `InvalidQueryError`.